# Addition with 7-Segment Display

Tags: case, vhdl, seven-segment-display

I am trying to add the 2 outputs together and show their result in a third/fourth display on the 7 segment display. Each output is shown in their own segment respectively. The fourth display being a double digit number (Max being 14, Min being 0). I am getting an error stating that I need to write all instances of the case "add". Not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
ENTITY  Midterm2_Q2_4369 IS
PORT (

SW: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
SW0: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);

ADD: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);
Y: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);
Y0: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);
Y1: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0);

Y2: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(6 DOWNTO 0));
END Midterm2_Q2_4369;
ARCHITECTURE MUX8 OF Midterm2_Q2_4369 IS 
BEGIN
PROCESS (SW,SW0,ADD)
BEGIN
CASE SW IS
WHEN "000" => Y <= "0000001";

WHEN "001" => Y <= "1001111";

WHEN "010" => Y <= "0010010";

WHEN "011" => Y <= "0000110";

WHEN "100" => Y <= "1001100";

WHEN "101" => Y <= "0100100";

WHEN "110" => Y <= "0100000";

WHEN "111" => Y <= "0001111";
END CASE;

CASE SW0 IS
WHEN "000" => Y0 <= "0000001";

WHEN "001" => Y0 <= "1001111";

WHEN "010" => Y0 <= "0010010";

WHEN "011" => Y0 <= "0000110";

WHEN "100" => Y0 <= "1001100";

WHEN "101" => Y0 <= "0100100";

WHEN "110" => Y0 <= "0100000";

WHEN "111" => Y0 <= "0001111";
END CASE;

CASE ADD IS
WHEN "0000000" => Y1 <= "0000001"; --0

WHEN "0000001" => Y1 <= "1001111"; --1

WHEN "0000010" => Y1 <= "0010010"; --2

WHEN "0000011" => Y1 <= "0000110"; --3

WHEN "0000100" => Y1 <= "1001100"; --4

WHEN "0000101" => Y1 <= "0100100"; --5

WHEN "0000110" => Y1 <= "0100000"; --6

WHEN "0000111" => Y1 <= "0001111"; --7

WHEN "0001111" => Y1 <= "0000000"; --8

WHEN "0010111" => Y1 <= "0000100"; --9
     --8421421
WHEN "0011111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)0

WHEN "0100111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)1

WHEN "0101111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)2

WHEN "0110111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)3

WHEN "0111111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)4--

WHEN "1000111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)5

WHEN "1001111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)6

WHEN "1010111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)7--

WHEN "1011111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)8

WHEN "1100111" => Y2 <= "1001111"; --(1)9
END CASE;

END PROCESS;
END MUX8;
```

Comment: Just use `WHEN OTHERS => Y2 <=<something>;` to cover the ones you're not interested in.

Answer (score 2):

When using a `case` in VHDL, all cases MUST be covered.
Becasue `SW`, `SW0` and `ADD` are all `std_logic_vector`, you must also cover all of the meta cases like "UUUUUUUU", etc. The easiest way to do this is with `others`.

For example. SW0 has all "real" cases covered, but you must also cover values that can only occur in simulation, so provide a handy message:

```vhdl
CASE SW0 IS
  WHEN "000" => Y0 <= "0000001";
  WHEN "001" => Y0 <= "1001111";
  WHEN "010" => Y0 <= "0010010";
  WHEN "011" => Y0 <= "0000110";
  WHEN "100" => Y0 <= "1001100";
  WHEN "101" => Y0 <= "0100100";
  WHEN "110" => Y0 <= "0100000";
  WHEN "111" => Y0 <= "0001111";
  when others => report "Meta value detected" severity warning;-- simulation only case
END CASE;
```

You must also ensure all cases are covered for `SW` and `ADD` too